# Typeface identification: Garamond variant

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces, serif, latex

## Problem

I’m trying to identify the precise typeface used in the following document:
[image: Document whose typeface I am trying to identify]

## Context and current state of my investigations

I know this document was generated using LaTeX; unfortunately I do not have access to the original file, but just the image above.

By analyzing the different fonts visible on this document, one can see that this typeface is quite close to Garamond. In particular, there are some remarkable characteristics:

- the characteristic rounded right inward serif of the lowercase italic `h`;
- the uppercase roman `C` does not have upward-pointing serif;
- the overrun to the left of the upper bar of the lowercase italic `p`;
- the bar of the uppercase roman `G` is double sided;
- the uppercase roman `A` does have a cusp to the left;
- the elongated form of the lowarcase italic `f`;
- the alignment of the bar of the lowercase roman `e`.

I therefore carried out investigations by looking for Garamond variants, focusing in particular on typefaces accessible directly with LaTeX packages, and broadening my search afterwards.

In the end, even though I found relatively similar candidates, none of them were a perfect match. In particular, several characteristics make it a bit different from the usual Garamond variants. E.g.:

- the centre bar of the uppercase `P` meets the vertical perfectly (the `P` is thus closed);
- the upper bar of the uppercase `T` does not have upward-pointing serifs.

These differences make me wonder if this is really a variant of Garamond, or rather another—close but different—typeface.

Comment: do you have the pdf?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Unfortunately no (otherwise the identification would have been much simpler )… As stated in the post I do not have access to the original file, but just the given image.

Comment: @mipo Oh, I thought with "original file" you meant the .tex file - sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No problem, my wording could indeed be misleading!

Comment: I was thinking it looks a lot like Equity (which was made specifically for lawyers and legal texts), but it wasn’t that – though it is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

This sent me down quite the rabbit hole, so even if I am not sure what font this is, here's what I found. There are [about a million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garamond#Contemporary_versions) Garamond variations, and their history is fascinating.

Seeing the context it might indeed (as was already noted) be an open source spin on Equity, the legal font, and it is also similar to Linux Libertine. I don't think it's a Garamond clone as much as a similar font: Garamond is freely available in tex.

What you sent is similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garamond#/media/File:ATF_1923_Garamond_specimen_page_22b.jpg), but it doesn't match neither Garamond Monospace nor Garamont.